# Submitting spark applications to yarn programmatically

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn

I feel that it is becoming a very common requirement to be able to submit spark applications programmatically to yarn. However there is no references about it in apache spark documentation. Is it even possible and if it is, is there a straight forward way to achieve it. Please advise.

Comment: I have the same issue. People run Spark jobs as a one off computation task and SparkSubmit works perfect for this purpose. But if one wants to have more control we need to be able to new SparkContext("yarn-client") and use it.

Example of usecase is an web app that crunches and visualizes data and wants to directly use the results of RDDs and use heavy caching in a session.

FYI. I am using SparkContext in my Java app and works very well except I can't get it to work with Yarn and there is no way for me to do what I do now with spark-submit properly

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do this is to turn your driver application into an RPC server. That way, you only fire up a single SparkContext. Your incoming RPC requests all re-use your existing SparkContext.

The documents mention this strategy in passing, I believe, but otherwise this is really beyond the scope of the Spark docs.

I did this recently using [http4s](http://http4s.org/), an embeddable, functional HTTP server. It was trivial.

But pick your RPC protocol of choice and have at it.

Comment: I would also recommend looking up Spark's scheduling logic, since that's a very important aspect of this approach. It's documented here: http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/job-scheduling.html#scheduling-within-an-application

Answer (score 0):

[You can call `SparkSubmit` from code](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/b1f4ca82d170935d15f1fe6beb9af0743b4d81cd/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/deploy/SparkSubmit.scala#L105):

```
org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(/*Submission args*/)
```

Comment: I don't believe so. You want something where you can pass it a self contained program via a function pointer as the main? AFAIK, that does not exist currently, but I can review the code some more to verify.

Comment: After much hair pulling I got this working.  But it has a fatal flaw... the call to SparkSubmit.main() launches a monitoring thread and does not return until the job is complete, just like when you go through the shell.  This is useless for my use case, which was to "fire and forget" many thousands of spark jobs.